# Testlink api python

Tags: python, python-3.7, testlink

I'm using TestLink-API-Python-client to work with Testlink application API. So, I need to get all testcases for the TestSuite with `execution_type = 1` or `execution_type = 2` to calculate the quantity of automated and manual tests (when execution_type = 1 it's manual tests, when execution_type = 2, it's automated tests). 
For this purpose I used next method from the library `getTestCasesForTestSuite(testsuite["id"], True, "full", getkeywords=True)` as the result I got issue:

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/user1/PycharmProjects/script_for_testlink/script_for_testlink.py", line 871, in <module>
result = getAutomatedTestcasesForProject(TESTLINK_API_URL, TESTLINK_API_DEVKEY, project_in_testlink)

File "C:/Users/user1/PycharmProjects/script_for_testlink/script_for_testlink.py", line 112, in getAutomatedTestcasesForProject
testcases_for_testsuites = testlink.getTestCasesForTestSuite(testsuite["id"], True, "full", getkeywords=True)

File "C:\Users\user1\TAF\venv\lib\site-packages\testlink\testlinkdecorators.py", line 140, in wrapperReplaceTLResponseError
response = methodAPI(self, *argsPositional, **argsOptional)

File "C:\Users\user1\TAF\venv\lib\site-packages\testlink\testlinkdecorators.py", line 112, in wrapperAddDevKey
return methodAPI(self, *argsPositional, **argsOptional)

File "C:\Users\user1\TAF\venv\lib\site-packages\testlink\testlinkdecorators.py", line 100, in wrapperWithArgs
*argsPositional, **argsOptional)

File "C:\Users\user1\TAF\venv\lib\site-packages\testlink\testlinkapigeneric.py", line 1517, in callServerWithPosArgs
response = self._callServer(methodNameAPI, argsOptional)

File "C:\Users\user1\TAF\venv\lib\site-packages\testlink\testlinkapigeneric.py", line 1992, in _callServer
response = getattr(self.server.tl, methodNameAPI)(argsAPI)

File "c:\users\user1\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\Lib\xmlrpc\client.py", line 1117, in __call__
return self.__send(self.__name, args)

 File "c:\users\user1\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\Lib\xmlrpc\client.py", line 1457, in __request
verbose=self.__verbose

File "c:\users\user1\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\Lib\xmlrpc\client.py", line 1159, in request
return self.single_request(host, handler, request_body, verbose)

 File "c:\users\user1\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\Lib\xmlrpc\client.py", line 1175, in single_request
return self.parse_response(resp)

File "c:\users\user1\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\Lib\xmlrpc\client.py", line 1345, in parse_response
p.close()

File "c:\users\user1\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\Lib\xmlrpc\client.py", line 453, in close
parser.Parse(b"", True) # end of data
xml.parsers.expat.ExpatError: not well-formed (invalid token): line 5186, column 0
```

How can I get testcases with field `execution_type` without issues?

Comment: You cut off the exception name and parameters, and left only the stacktrace. What was in the exception?

Comment: What do you mean, @9000? I just copied all the errors from the console, what exception you need and what parameters? I think I sent all the data

Comment: Please disregard; I found the actual error message at the bottom.

Comment: Apparently the response from the server arrives empty. Are you sure your URL and API key are fine?

Comment: @9000 yes, sure, for some test cases this method is working fine, I'm looking for solution on the Internet and have found some reasons why it can be, but don't know how to fix. It seems that when this method parse data, this data contain some forbidden symbols.